# How to check if an HttpSession is invalid without having the request

Tags: java, session, httpsession

I have a Map of HttpSession and ip that is added when a request is initialized. It normally remove when session is destroyed but sometimes that doesn't happen and I want to do it by hand.

How to remove sessions that are already invalidated from this map?

**Listener**

```
...
private static final Map<HttpSession, String> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent ev) {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ev.getServletRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if(session.isNew()){
            sessions.put(session, request.getRemoteAddr());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent ev) {
        sessions.remove(ev.getSession());
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this way and it seems to work fine!

```
public static void cleanUpMemorySessions() {
    sessions.entrySet().forEach((entry) -> {
        try {
            entry.getKey().isNew();
        } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
            sessions.remove(entry.getKey());
        }
    });
}
```